# how to define two dimensional string , not a char vector in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

i want to define the two dimensional string , not a char vector in C++ Like this :

```
vector<vector<char>> vect
{
        {"Simple", "Simple", "Simple"},
        {"Simple", "Simple", "Simple"},
        {"Simple", "Simple", "Simple"}
};
```

Thanks

Comment: So what you want is a vector of vectors of **`std::string`**?

Comment: What does "two dimensional string" mean?

Comment: If you want to define a "two dimensional string" in code, you must first define it in words so that we have some idea what you mean. What properties must it have? Why specifically is `vector<vector<char>>` not suitable?

Comment: your initializer is for a 2d vector of strings, but `vect` is declared as 2d vector of characters, hence it is not clear which you want

Comment: It does not matter if it is a vector or an array, but I need something like this to have a two-dimensional string array.

Comment: what is "something like this" ? It can be either a 2d vector of characters or a 2d vector of strings, but not both

Comment: OK, and how does it need to behave? What operations must it support? Should each element be a string? Should each row be a string? Should each column be a string? Is it fixed-width? Fixed-height? Variable in both dimensions?

Comment: Yes, each element is a string and all rows and columns are strings but the length and width are variable.

Comment: if you have a 2d vector of strings then each element is a vector of strings (not a string). And each element of the inner vector is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your declaration the type does not match the initializer. You either want a 2d vector of strings:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vect
{
        {"Simple", "Simple", "Simple"},
        {"Simple", "Simple", "Simple"},
        {"Simple", "Simple", "Simple"}
};
```

Or a 2D vector of characters, ie a 1D vector of strings where the strings are stored as `std::vector<char>`:

```
vector<vector<char>> vect
{
        {'s', 'i', 'm'},
        {'p', 'l', 'e'},
        {'f', 'o', 'o'}
};
```

As it is unclear what you actually want, a third alternative is a vector of  strings (which can be considered as 2d container of characters):

```
std::vector<std::string> vect
{
        "Simple", "Simple", "Simple",
        "Simple", "Simple", "Simple",
        "Simple", "Simple", "Simple"
};
```

Comment: I mean the first case you gave as an example